# Django ModelForm label captialisation

Tags: django, django-forms

In my model I have;

```
title = models.CharField(verbose_name="eBay Listing Title",max_length=56)
```

Using a ModelForm the label shows as "EBay Listing Title" (capital E). I'm using

```
{{ field.label_tag }}
```

on the form template (in a loop) to display the labels.

How can I get the label to show correctly with a lowercase first letter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can override the label in the form

for example:

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].label = "eBay Listing Title"

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
```

Answer (score 5):

Pass in the `label` argument
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#label

The capitalization is just a default -- replacing underscores with spaces and capitalizing if you don't pass in anything.

Example from docs:

```
>>> class CommentForm(forms.Form):
...     name = forms.CharField(label='Your name')
```